# How to choose a word of more than 5 letters?

Tags: python, if-statement, random, controls

I was trying to randomly select a word from a word list.
However, since the word list (from file:///usr/share/dict/words; Mac OS) contains almost every word, I wish to ignore those words containing 5 letters or less.

```
#Getting words from words.txt (retrieved from file:///usr/share/dict/words)
wordList = open(wordBank).readlines()
while True:
    wordChosen = random.choice(wordList)
    if len(wordchosen) > 5:
        break
    else:
        xxxxxxxx
print wordChosen
```

How should I code the "else" part where it tells the computer to re-run the random selection until a word with more than 5 letters is found? Can it be performed by using if-else statements?

Comment: So you're just trying to select one word?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the else statement!

```
while True:
    wordChosen = random.choice(wordList)
    if len(wordchosen) > 5:
        break

print wordChosen
```

Comment: Oh my. I didn't know that I actually do not need "else" statement >< Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to put anything in the else block, and it can be safely removed. Due to the while loop with a True condition, your code will run until it finds a word longer than 5 characters long, at which point the loop will break (although it could potentially run forever!) and the word will be printed.

Comment: Oh my. I didn't know that I actually do not need "else" statement >< Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your OP post you said: *I was trying to randomly select a word from a word list*. If I understand you correctly, you want to randomly select one word but only if the word has at least 5 characters.

If so, this is one way to do it:

```
wordList = open(wordBank).readlines()
wordChosen = random.choice(wordList)
while len(wordChosen) < 5:
    continue
print (wordChosen)
```